# canvas.drawText changes anti-alias flag of paint object, is this an Android bug?

Tags: android, android-canvas

There was a curious bug in my app where the `Paint.measureText(String text)` was returning a different answer when it seemed to me it should be returning the same value.  Eventually I tracked it down to the ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG being being changed when I used the Paint object to draw the text, i.e.

```
Paint text_paint = new Paint(); 
text_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
text_paint.setTextSize(50);
text_paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);    
Log.d("MyApp","AA1="+text_paint.isAntiAlias());
canvas.drawText("SomeText", 10, 10, text_paint);
Log.d("MyApp","AA2="+text_paint.isAntiAlias());
```

with Android version 4.2.1 produced the log output

```
04-29 19:30:00.702: D/MyApp(18806): AA1=false
04-29 19:30:00.707: D/MyApp(18806): AA2=true
```

And the result of `measureText` depends on this ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG.  So my questions are

1. What is this ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG, and what determines whether one chooses to set it true or false?
2. It seems to me that a call like `canvas.drawText(...)` shouldn't alter the paint object being used, so what on earth is going on, and is this a bug?

Comment: What is `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG`.  Is Google down at the moment?  I'm guessing at the second part.  You normally want to anti-alias when drawing text so my guess is that drawing without it, sets the flag by default.  What happens if you set it first (either on or off)?

Comment: A new paint object has it set false.  If I manually set it false it produces the same output as reported in my question, and if I set it true it remains true before and after the drawText.  And, just for the record, the Android help didn't have the useful remark "You normally want to anti-alias when drawing text".

Comment: Hmm, smells like a bug.  I would test for you on some other version but not at my dev machine at the moment.  What does it do in the emulator with something much older, e.g. Froyo?  it would be interesting to extend `Paint` and override the `setAntiAlias()` method to see if it's being called (and if it is, offers a workaround).